# Paypal modifying the price issue

Tags: paypal

I have a simple IPN script but users can modify the price of the package in the URL.
An example would be: Package price is $500 but they change it to 1 cent and then pay and
they still become activated. IS there any way to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the price in your IPN script, and if it doesn't agree with the database you should reject the transaction. Better still, do nothing, that way you get to keep the money, and let them complain about it.